# Hadoop avro correct jar files issue

Tags: hadoop, jar, mapreduce, avro

I'm writing my first Avro job that is meant to take an avro file and output text. I tried to reverse engineer it from this example:

https://gist.github.com/chriswhite199/6755242

I am getting the error below though.

Error: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but class was expected

I looked around and found it was likely an issue with what jar files are being used. I'm running CDH4 with MR1 and am using the jar files below:

avro-tools-1.7.5.jar

hadoop-core-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0.jar

hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.0.2-alpha.jar

I can't post code for security reasons but it shouldn't need anything not used in the example code. I don't have maven set up yet either so I can't follow those routes. Is there something else I can try to get around these issues?

Answer (score 0):

Try using avro 1.7.3

[AVRO-1170 bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1170)

Comment: Switching to 1.7.3 is messing up a lot of dependencies. I ended up using pig for dealing with avro for right now. Thanks for the heads up on the bug though.